# How to make a button play a sound as it launches another activity when pressed?

Tags: java, android, onclick, playsound

Current code:

```
   MediaPlayer mp;

    button1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity1.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
```

So how would a button start a new activity and play a sound while doing so?

What I've tried: various methods like playSound( ); in the method.

It only plays the default android sound. I want a specific sound stored in the raw directory. So when the button get's pressed it launches both the intent to launch the activity as well as the specific sound.

Error:

When I try to put MediaPlayer mp; above the button, it states variable mp is already defined. I just need someone to append the activity launch code so that it will play the sound as well.

Comment: a sound should be played by default, when you press on a button, if you didn't specify differently on your phone's settings

Comment: is sound file place in the application or you want stream?

Comment: @Blackbelt I mean a specific sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to put a sound.mp3 in raw folder
    MediaPlayer mp;

```
button1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Music.this, R.raw.sound);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                try {
                    mp.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mp.start();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity1.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

});
```

Comment: then make the variable final and try it outside the onCreate method like    final MediaPlayer mp;

Comment: is the MediaPlayer mp declared outside the OnCreate method. Just try declaring it above ** @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)**

Comment: Thanks Journey, I would also upvote you but I don't have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(""));
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                player.start();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity1.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to release it : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29

```
Mediaplayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.YOURMP3NAMEFILE);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if(mp != null){
                mp.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
                Log.d(TAG, "release mediaplayer");
            }
        }
    });
mediaPlayer.start();
launchSecondActivity();
```